# How do I create a method that displays how many elements are in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm fairly new to Java, but here's my problem.

I've created an array method that holds a block of 10 integers, which the user will input.  They will enter -1 when they are finished, however the -1 will be stored. Here's my code for that:

```
    public static int [] inputGrades()
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
        int [] iGrades = new int [10];
        System.out.print("\nInput test scores, enter -1 when you're finished.\n");
        for (int i =0; i<iGrades.length;i++)
        {
            if (iGrades[i]>=-1)
            {
                iGrades[i]=kb.nextInt();
                break;
            }
        }
        return iGrades;   
    }
```

After that I'm to create a method that is supposed to count how many number values there are up to the -1. So say, the user entered 5 numbers and -1, I'd display 6. Here's what I have for that:

```
public static int countArrayElements(int[] array)
    {
        int iCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
        {
            if (array[i] != 0)
            {
            iCount ++;
            }
        System.out.print ("\nThere are " + iCount + "numbers in the array.");
        }
        return iCount;
    }
```

All it's returning is 10 ones though.  A nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: yes, `-1` is `!= 0`, you probably want `!= -1`, **or** change the `if(iGrades[i]>=-1)`

Comment: Why not adding the entered values (not equal to -1) to an ArrayList? Then the size of the List would give you already the number of entered values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with both of your methods, Change them to the following, First initialize your array:

```
public static int [] inputGrades(){
    System.out.print("\nInput test scores, enter -1 when you're finished.\n");
    Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
    int [] iGrades = new int [10];
    for (int i =0; i<iGrades.length;i++){
      iGrades[i] = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }
    for (int i =0; i<iGrades.length;i++){
        iGrades[i]=kb.nextInt();
        if (iGrades[i] ==-1)
           break;
    }
    kb.close(); // Don't forget to close the scanner
    return iGrades;   
}


public static int countArrayElements(int[] array){
        int iCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i ++)
        {   
          if(array[i] > -1){           
              iCount++;
          }
        }
        System.out.print ("\nThere are " + iCount + " numbers in the array.");
        return iCount;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that did it.  My problem was my if statement `if iGrades[i]<=-1`

Comment: for the count it would add the -1 to my count, How would I make it to where the -1 would not count towards iCount?

Comment: I've tried that already, it displays 9 regardless of how many numbers I've entered.

Comment: I figured it out, I just made it `if(array[i]>0)` thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Each component of the one-dimensional array is initialized to its default value. So for int it's 0, that your method return array's length. Check [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6)

Answer (score -1):

May be you need to use, if else condition to break the loop..

```
    for (int i =0; i<iGrades.length;i++)
    {
        if (iGrades[i]==-1)
        {
            break;

        }
        else{
            iGrades[i]=kb.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

This loop accepts 10 elements , and it the user enters only -1 it will break.

```
public static int countArrayElements(int[] array)
{
    int iCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] != -1)
        {
        iCount ++;
        }
    }
    System.out.print ("\nThere are " + (iCount+1) + "numbers in the array.");
    return iCount;
}
```

Here printing of (iCount+1) is to count -1 also.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of two methods, it can be possible in  single method as i did using `ArrayList`

```
public static int inputGrades()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    int GRADE_SIZE = 10;

    List<Integer> iGrades = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.print("\nInput test scores, enter -1 when you're finished.\n");

    for (int idx = 0; idx < GRADE_SIZE; idx++)
    {
        int inputNum = scanner.nextInt();
        iGrades.add(inputNum);

        if(inputNum == -1){
            break;
        }
    }

    return iGrades.size();   
}
```

**Main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
System.out.println("Grade Size :: "+inputGrades());
}
```